# Android Application Access SQLite Database on Laptop/Server

Tags: java, android, sqlite

currently I am developing Android application by using Java (Android native) and sqlite database. What I want is to have 1 sqlite database in the server, which will be accessed by my apps from different device.

Since I don't have any server yet and the application still under development, for now I am planning to access the database, which stored in my laptop (my laptop as the server). But, I don't know how to do so. I am trying to find any references through google, but it did not help.

I am new to Android Native. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access _the whole SQLite database file_ from the server? I.e have a local copy of it on the device and then use it on device side?

Comment: no, for now, i don't think i will need local copy of database. What I want is just, the app to access sqlite file in the server (in my computer in this case).

Comment: You'll need a webservice for that. Check out this tutorial.http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Comment: In that case, to get you started, there should be plenty of examples how to read files over the Internet using http for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use another database like SQL Server. then you can call some web services.